# How to find median value for five given elements based on the max min and sum of the elements

Tags: median, arithmetic

this question occurred in my interview,

How to find the median values using the min, max, and sum values of the given 5 elements?

for eg if given 3 elements we can use
sum - min - max

a = [3,6,9]
here median is 6
min = 3
max = 9
sum = 18

18 - 9- 3 = 6
which is the same as median values.

so the question is how to find the median for the 5 elements?

find for the a = [1,2,3,4,10]

Answer (score 17):

If you only know the min, max, and sum of the 5 numbers, you cannot determine the median.
E.g.

median(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)=3
median(1, 2.1, 2.8, 4.1, 5)=2.8.

But both have (min, max, sum) = (1, 5, 15).

Answer (score 1):

Find the max and min of the initial list.
Create a new list without those 2 elements.
Find the new max, min and sum and use the method you mentioned,

median = sum - min - max

Comment: Or do the "throw away min and max" step twice.

Comment: This assumes knowing all five numbers, hence an ability to find the median directly, not from the max, min and sum only...

Comment: I suspect that this is the answer sought  by the person originally proposing the riddle.